# How to change result of hostname command

Tags: linux, centos-7, hosts-file, hostname

when I issue a `hostname` command in my Centos 7 server, I get this response:

`vps.example.com`

I have changed `/etc/hosts` file with this:

`204.93.xxx.xxx mail.example.com`

However, when I issue `hostname` command again, the same response is shown.

Am I changing the right file? Do I need to reboot or is there another way to refresh that information?

Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to edit /etc/host**name** as well.  Once you have done this A reboot will fix it but is not necessary.  Type "hostname mail.example.com" to avoid needing a reboot.

The hostname command both reads and sets the hostname, and is called during startup.

If your shell uses the hostname in the prompt you will need to log out and log in to get a shell with the updated hostname (but launching programs using the hostname will use the new one)

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS 7 you have a utility that helps you set the hostname
`hostnamectl set-hostname <HOSTNAME>`
Although changes will not be visible as soon as you fire command. You can check it with `hostname` command. And on the next login it will show the new hostname in command prompt.